# Is there a real positive function such that $\min\{f(x),f(y)\}<|x-y|$, if $x\neq y$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering if there exists a function $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, such that $f(x)>0$, for all $x$, and $\min\{f(x),f(y)\}<|x-y|$, if $x\neq y$.

Comment: I want to say the following:

If it did, then for any $x$ we'd have that for any $y$, $\min \{f(x), f(y)\} < |x-y|$. By assumption $f(x)$ is positive so as $y \to x$ we have $f(y) \to 0$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$ let $\delta_x$ such that $f(y) < \varepsilon$ for any $|y - x| < \delta_x$. Obviously the balls $B_{\delta_x}(x)$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ cover $\mathbb{R}$. Hence for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $f < \varepsilon$, which is impossible.

But there's one thing I can't iron out: we only have bounds on $y \neq x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that such a function does not exist by contradiction.

Suppose it does.

Fix $x$, for any $y \in B_{f(x)} (x) $ (distinct from x), we get that $\min\{f(x), f(y) \} < |x-y| < f(x)$, hence $f(y) < f(x)$. This is the important property which we will be using.

Now, define a series of points recursively.

Start with any $x_0 = x$.
Let $x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)} {2}.$
Let $x_2 = x_1 + \frac{ f(x_1)} { 2^2}$.
In general, $x_{n+1} = x_n + (-1)^n \frac{f(x_n)} { 2^n} $.

**Hint:** Let $x^*$ be the accumulation point of $x_n$. Why does this exist? Show that $x^* \neq x_n$ for all $n$. Show also that $x^* \in B_{f(x_n)} (x_n) $ for all $n$.

**Hint:** Consider $x^*$. Show that there exists an $x_N \in B_{f(x^*)}(x^*)$. Hence conclude that $f(x^*) < f( x_N)$ and $f(x_N) < f(x^*)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,. I really don't understand why $f(x*)<f(xn)$.

Comment: @FagnerSantana Remember what I said was the important property. Why must  $x^*$ is in the ball $B_{f(x_n)} (x_n)$?

Comment: Ok, but  what i cant't see is $x*\in B_{f(x_n)}(x_n)$.

Comment: Look at the construction of $x^*$. Draw out the points $x_n$, can you see that $x^*$ lies in the interval $x_{n}, x_{n+1}$? Why does that tell you that it lies in a ball of radius $f(x_n)$?

Comment: Ok, after a good time thinking about your solution i finally understand. Thanks.

Comment: @FagnerSantana If so, please vote up and/or accept this. Alternatively, if you feel that much more details would be better, please post a complete solution for others to understand.

Comment: @CalvinLin : your general recurrence doesn't match with the special initial terms ( may be that's a typo ) and could you please elaborate  why $x^*$ lies in between $x_n,x_{n+1}$ for every $n$ ?